# Subtracting an integer value from a text file and displaying the result in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, text-manipulation

I have a text file which has something like

```
00:47:12: start interaction

00:47:18: End interaction

00:47:20: Start interaction

00:47:23: End interaction

00:47:25: Start interaction

00:47:28: End interaction

00:47:29: Start interaction

00:47:31: End interaction
```

I would like to get the time stamp value from the file like **00:47:12:** and the next immediate value here **00:47:18:** and find the time difference between the values in this case **6 seconds**  and print as the output. Would be great to have some possible suggestions. I tried to implement the first part of getting the seconds value but I am stuck here.

Code:

```
with open('Time_delay', 'r') as time_delay:
                for line in time_delay:
                    time_stamp = re.findall(r"\:(.*?)\: ",line)
                    time_stamp = ''.join(time_stamp)
                    #time_stamp = re.findall(r"\:(.*?)\: ",str(time_stamp))
                    #time_stamp = ''.join(time_stamp)
                    print line 
                    print  str(time_stamp)
```

The first `re.findall` prints

```
47:12
47:18
```

SO thought of using the same method for the output of it to get only the last part which is `12` and `18` in this case and then perform the subtraction or difference. But I am unable to find the way to get only the last part and perform the calculation.

I want my output as

```
First interaction : 6 seconds
Second interaction : 3 seconds
Third interaction : 3 seconds
```

and so on

Comment: Why don't you convert them to `time`/`datetime` objects then just subtract them?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am pretty new to datetime object, it would be great help if you can provide an example implementation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try like this using `datetime` module

if your file is like this:

```
00:47:12: start interaction
00:47:18: End interaction
00:47:20: Start interaction
00:47:23: End interaction
00:47:25: Start interaction
00:47:28: End interaction
00:47:29: Start interaction
00:47:31: End interaction
```

code here:

```
>>> f = open('file.txt')
>>> for x in f:
...     start = x.split()[0][:-1]
...     end = f.next().split()[0][:-1]
...     print str(datetime.datetime.strptime(end,"%H:%M:%S")- datetime.datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M:%S")).split(':')[-1]
... 
06
03 
03
02
```

to handle empty lines:

```
>>> f = open('file.txt').readlines()
>>> my_file = [ x for x in f if x!='\n' ]
>>> for x in range(0,len(my_file)-1,2):
...     start = my_file[x].split()[0][:-1]
...     end = my_file[x+1].split()[0][:-1]
...     print str(datetime.datetime.strptime(end,"%H:%M:%S")- datetime.datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M:%S")).split(':')[-1]
... 
06
03
03
02
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last element you can use `look-behind` in regex :

```
>>> s = '00:47:12: start interaction'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\d{2}\:\d{2}\:)\d+',s).group(0)
'12'
```

and then convert it to `int` , then calculate the difference !

edit : as you may check the empty lines too you need to use an `if` :

```
 if re.search(r'(?<=\d{2}\:\d{2}\:)\d+',s) :
                print re.search(r'(?<=\d{2}\:\d{2}\:)\d+',s).group(0)
```

Also as another way you can split your lines and convert the string time to time :

```
>>> sp_line1= re.split(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):',s)
['00:47:12', ' start interaction']
```

Demo :

```
>>> t1= strptime(sp_line1[0],"%H:%M:%S")
>>> s2="00:47:18: End interaction"
>>> sp_line1=re.split(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):',s2)
>>> sp_line2=re.split(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):',s2)
>>> t2= strptime(sp_line2[0],"%H:%M:%S")
>>> t1.tm_sec
12
>>> t2.tm_sec - t1.tm_sec
6
```

Comment: I get an error while trying the first option. `time_stamp = re.findall(r"\:(.*?)\: ",line)
     time_stamp = ''.join(time_stamp)
     time_stamp = str(time_stamp)
     time_stamp_start = re.search(r'(?<=\d{2}\:\d{2}\:)\d+',time_stamp).group(0)` the error is **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Comment: @VenkateshPadmanabhan its because of empty lines (`\n`) you just need an exception , see the edit

Answer (score 0):

If your source file is consisently in the same format, that is each pair of lines with content form a `start / end` group, this will work.  It even accounts for blank lines.

```
from datetime import datetime

def calcTimes(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        parsedTimeArray = [line.split(': ')[0] for line in f if len(line.rstrip('\n')) != 0]
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    for t in range(0,(len(parsedTimeArray)-1),2):
        timeStart = datetime.strptime(parsedTimeArray[t],   format)
        timeEnd   = datetime.strptime(parsedTimeArray[t+1], format)
        print str(int((timeEnd - timeStart).total_seconds()))

calcTimes('Time_delay')
```

Result:

```
6
3
3
2
```